# How to limit # queries made when Django model property is based on ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, performance, django-rest-framework

I'm building a read API for an existing (legacy) SQL database using Django Rest Framework. The problem is that way too many queries are made.

I want to select a `Widget` and its (about 40) related widgets, including the `widget_technology` for each of the related widgets. The technology of a widget depends on the presence or absence of a certain tag (I realize it's suboptimal database design but it's legacy...). The problem is that this results in 40+ queries (one per related widget).

Is there any way to fix it?

I've been looking at `prefetch_related('widget_tags')` in the DRF part of the code, but that doesn't seem to help.

Here is the main table:

```
class Widgets(models.Model):
    widget_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    widget_slug = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=70)
    widget_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    widget_tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags', through='IsTag')
    related_widgets = models.ManyToManyField('Widgets', through='Similar', related_name='similar')

    @property
    def widget_technology(self):
        if self.widget_tags.filter(tag_slug='tech_1').exists():
            return 'TECH_1'
        elif self.widget_tags.filter(tag_slug='tech_2').exists():
            return 'TECH_2'

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'widgets'
```

For completeness, here are the other tables:

```
class Similar(models.Model):
    first_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        Widgets, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True, related_name='similar_first_widget'
    )
    second_widget = models.ForeignKey(
        Widgets, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='similar_second_widget'
    )
    score = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'similar'
        unique_together = (('first_widget', 'second_widget'),)

class IsTag(models.Model):
    is_tag_widget = models.ForeignKey(Widgets, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    is_tag_tag = models.ForeignKey('Tags', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'is_tag'
        unique_together = (('is_tag_widget', 'is_tag_tag'),)


class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tag_slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tags'
```

EDIT: Adding the View

```
class WidgetDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, slug):
        try:
            return Widgets.objects.get(widget_slug=slug)
            # tried this but didn't solve the issue:
            # return Widgets.objects.prefetch_related('related_widgets', 'related_widgets__widget_tags').get(widget_slug=slug)
    except Widgets.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    def get(self, request, slug, format=None):
        widget = self.get_object(slug)
        serializer = FullWidgetSerializer(widget)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and the serializers:

```
class FullWidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # special cases
    widget_tags = SimpleTagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    related_widgets = SimpleWidgetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Widgets     
        fields = (
            'widget_slug', 'related_widgets', 'widget_tags', 'widget_technology')

class SimpleWidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Widgets     
        fields = ('widget_slug', 'widget_technology')
```

Comment: Everyone forgets when to use prefetch_related and when to use select_related, so try one and if it doesn't work try the other :-)

Comment: Haha yes I tried both but only `prefetch_related` doesn't give an error (`select_related` gives `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related`).

Comment: post the relevent section of the view or viewset please

Comment: done! i also included the serializers :)

Comment: I guess I could just use a raw SQL query but I'm wondering if there's a better solution